# Find lowest value and return index number in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array that I build while looping through the result of a query in order to find all possible parts that can be used.

```
$_SESSION['opt'][$Id] = array('rawStock'=>$materialStockID,'cost'=>$material_cost);
```

I need to be able to find the lowest cost part and its part number (return all data for line). I am not opposed to using other methods to get the results. If there is an easier or more efficient method. The data is in a MySQL database.

Comment: `SELECT stockID, cost FROM table ORDER BY cost LIMIT 1`

Comment: just use a select statement just like the statement above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with this simple query:

```
SELECT stockID, cost FROM table ORDER BY cost LIMIT 1
```

If you don't want to do another query, then you can find the lowest price while you're looping over the results of the query:

```
$lowest_price = 99999999; // make this larger than any possible price
while ($row = fetch()) {
    // all your other code that processes the row here
    if ($material_cost < $lowest_price) {
        $lowest_price = $material_cost;
        $lowest_part = $materialStockID;
    }
}
```